# VS Code adding trailing "index.js" when renaming files

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code 1.33.1 (Linux), I'm trying to refactor (rename) JavaScript files, but it works partially.

Suppose I have a file `app.js` containing

```
import {Foo} from './bar.js';
```

If I drag the file `bar.js` into a subfolder named `subfolder1` the line above becomes

```
import {Foo} from './subfolder1/bar.js/index.js';
```

So VS Code is adding a trailing `/index.js`. How do I prevent this??

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, I'm also using native modules like the browser intended.

It's strange that a VSCode defaults to behaviour ment for webpack/babel and other stuff and breaks with default javascript definitions. Also auto adding the 1st import always forgets to add the extention. After it finds a import with an extention it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with VS Code for Windows. Just updated to the latest version and now (version 1.74.3) there are some options in settings (*JavaScript > Preferences: Import Module Specifier Ending*). You can choose preferred path ending. I guess they introduced the same feature on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ESM files, and you have a `jsconfig.js` file, you have to set the `moduleResolution` to `nodenext` in the `compilerOptions`.
That was a solution for me to fix the `/index.js` after renaming files.

Answer (score -1):

If you remove the '.js' this will work just fine, so unless you are using native module imports that solution will work just grand.

Comment: He is using native module imports.